# How can I pass arguments to a make rule?

Tags: makefile, command-line, arguments, sh, command-line-arguments

Suppose I had a python project that uses make to install. I want to be able to run the project without installing it first. So I created this make rule:

```
run:
    @echo "Running projectname"
    @PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$(abs_srcdir)/..; ./projectname
```

Where `./projectname` runs a simple python script that sets up and runs the project, but that's not important here. Like that, I can simply execute `make run` in the root folder of the project to execute and test my application, which works perfectly fine. Now, I want to pass some command line arguments to the program. I tried `make run --help`, which just printed `make`'s help text. Running `make run -- --help` printed

```sh
Running projectname
make: *** No rule to make target '--help'.  Stop.
```

The application is run, and after I exit it, `make` tries to execute a target `--help`.

Now, how can I pass for example a `--help` argument to my application through `make` ?

Comment: This isn't what `make` is for. Just write a simple wrapper script that sets `PYTHONPATH` appropriately, then pass its own arguments on to `projectname`.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  Make's command line is interpreted by make.  It's not passed to programs that make runs.  As described in the answer, you can set a make variable to some value then use that variable in your makefile, because make interprets variable assignments in its command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `make` like this:

```bash
make run ARGS=“arg1 arg2”
```

Then in your Makefile use:

```
run:
    @echo "Running projectname"
    @PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$(abs_srcdir)/..; ./projectname ${ARGS}
```

Comment: How will you handle something like `./projectname "arg one" "arg two"`?

Comment: @chepner -- you would just do `make run ARGS='"arg one" "arg two"'` (or escape the quotes...).